# how do i stop root from running a program

Tags: permissions, root

I would like to prevent my root user from running certain applications that can change the permissions of files which in turn prevents normal users from running those applications again.

for example, if i sudo to root, and then run thunderbird from the command prompt, it changes the permissions of files within my home dir / profile so i can no longer run it as a normal user; what i would like to do is prevent root from running thunderbird and hence stop this user error from repeating itself.

any suggestions?

to clarify,

if i have a lot of administration to do i use "sudo -s" which gives me a root shell, its just once a year or so, i shoot myself in the foot.

Comment: `"if I sudo to root"`  does this mean that you are typing `sudo thunderbird` or you are logging in as a root user then starting thunderbird?

Comment: Why would you ever run Thunderbird as root?

Comment: good question @mikewhatever , I was wondering the same myself.....

Comment: i use sudo -s, when i have a long series of commands, its a bad habit i know.
... and no i cant think of any reason why you would run thunderbird as root, so i wanted a technique to stop myself from doing it by accident.

Comment: What you are basically asking is "How to protect a system from its administrator", which is not something Linux is very good at. Root access is necessary and useful (not a bad habbit at all), but you can't avoid having to learn how to use it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have `thunderbird` installed locally, somewhere in your home directory then you could change the permissions to `500` so that only you can execute that program.

Run this on the executable

```
chmod 500 thunderbird
```

Also as TrailRider has said, don't run programs by prefixing `sudo`, it can be potentially [dangerous](http://www.howtogeek.com/124950/htg-explains-why-you-shouldnt-log-into-your-linux-system-as-root/). You can fix the permissions by changing the ownership of the `thunderbird` directory to your user name.

Comment: will permission `500` stop a `sudo` command from working?  What about a user logged in as a super user?  I thought that administrator accounts could override the permissions?

Comment: The administrator should be able to change permissions.

Comment: ok that's what I thought, thanks for the clarification...

Comment: Not sure how this got to be accepted. This literally doesn't work. root can run any program that has any execute bit set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe as this is a case of stopping a bone headed user shoot them selves in the foot that there is no easy way to do this. with great power comes great responability, and it would probably be best if learnt not to use sudo -s quite so often.

that being said, i am going to wrap a bash script around thunderbird, that checks the user name using whoami or $SUDO_USER and then aborts if it is an administrator. its not a general solution, but it will help in this isolated case.

Answer (score 0):

I have the habit of opening an extra session for root access with `sudo su -` and with a conspicuous prompt. This stops me from doing stupid things with sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the program's source code, find `main()`, add the lines

```
if (geteuid() == 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Access by root is disabled.\n");
    exit(255);
}
```

recompile and install.